# How to adapt current code to run without using a form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

How would I adapt this code to run without using the form, but the prompt() method instead? By including a prompt instead of a form to ask for user input.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms;text-align="center";font-size:20pt; color:#00FF00;>Simple Login Page</h1>
        <form name="login">
            Username<input type="text" name="userid"/>
            Password<input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
            <input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
            <input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
        </form>
        <script language="javascript">
            function check(form)/*function to check userid & password*/ {
                /*the following code checkes whether the entered userid and password are matching*/
                if(form.userid.value == "myuserid" && form.pswrd.value == "mypswrd") {
                    window.open('target.html')/*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
                }
                else {
                    alert("Error Password or Username")/*displays error message*/
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think `prompt` only lets you take in one value, but I think we're looking at the wrong issue altogether.  If you embed the username and password into your javascript, anyone can view the source and get the information.

Comment: Maybe "Basic HTTP Authentication" would be useful: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html